# Atualizar a versão do package.json automaticamente

Tags: node.js, git, npm

Antes de fazer um pequeno release e marcá-lo, gostaria de atualizar o package.json para refletir a nova versão do programa.

Existe uma maneira de editar o arquivo package.json automaticamente?

Ex: atualmente a aplicação está na versão 1.0.2 e quando eu fizer uma alteração na branch X ele muda para 1.0.3 automaticamente

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: npm update....?

Comment: @RenatoC.Francisco versão da aplicação não das bibliotecas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente rodar o comando:
`npm version patch`